# Is it possible to add a password to a child in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am making a room with channels which users can join and create. However, I want the users give an option to add a password to that channel they have created. Now I was wondering if it is possible to add a password in Firebase which is encrypted. One option, of course, is uploading the password in a string in Firebase like a normal value, but this is readable by anyone (since the .read rule says true). That way, anyone can see the password which is not what I want. So my question is: is this possible, and if yes: how? Below is some code that may can help.

Create channel IBAction function:

```
@IBAction func createChannel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let name = newChannelTextField?.text {
        let newChannelRef = channelRef.childByAutoId()
        let channelItem = [
            "name": name
        ]
        newChannelRef.setValue(channelItem)
    }
}
```

Channel.swift:

```
internal class Channel {
    internal let id: String
    internal let name: String

    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Did select cell function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        if indexPath.section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue
        {
            if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""
            {
                let channel = filteredChannels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                sendStatisticsToChannel(channel: channel)
                     }
            else
            {
                let channel = channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                sendStatisticsToChannel(channel: channel)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you have a server-side to check the password or you expose the password in your Firebase rules. The reason is that in order to check if a user inputs the correct password, it must be checked against the actual password. If they can check the actual password then they can read it to begin with. The same goes with encryption. If everything is done client side it will be possible for someone to reverse the process.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you have any idea how this can be done on the device? Is there a extension for encryption? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what device you're on, but most likely if your encryption algorithm is on user's devices it can be broken. You will need a server to use encryption or passwords. Have you considered another approach?